# How to do "hg mv --after" in git?

Tags: git

I renamed some files outside of git and modified them heavily. When I am running
`git diff-index -M --name-status HEAD` I see only 4 files as renamed/moved, whereas it should be more.

I know that I can record the move post factum in Mercurial using `hg mv --after`. I cannot find an equivalent in git. Is there?

Comment: I don't understand....you mean something like `git log` ?

Comment: `hg mv --after X Y` allows you to tell Mercurial that file X was renamed to Y, rather than keep the record of X being being deleted and Y being added. Note, that it works even though the file X no longer exists in the working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Summary:** Don't worry about it.  Just commit the file normally, because that's literally your only choice.

Here's how Git views a rename from X to Y.

```
Commit #1:
  - File named "X" with contents "Hello, world!"
Commit #2:
  - File named "Y" with contents "Hello, world!"
```

Notice that Git does not actually care if you renamed the file or if you created a new file with the same contents.  To Git, there is *no difference at all.*

Git does not record moves in the repository, and there is no per-file history.  Git only records history as a graph of snapshots of the *entire* repository.  Simply use `git add` and `git commit` as normal, nothing else you do here will have any effect.  If you use `git mv` it is just the same as `git rm` and `git add`.

When you use `git status` or `git log`, it will display a deletion and addition as a move if the added file is similar enough to the deleted file.  Git does not use any extra information in the repository.  If you change the moved file enough, it will show up as a separate addition and deletion instead.  Git does this by comparing the contents of the new file to the contents of the deleted file.  This happens when you ask for the diff, *after* the data is already committed.

The default similarity threshold is 50%.  If you want to see renames between files that are less than 50% similar, pass a lower percentage to `git diff-index`.  For example, to track renames even if 75% of the file changes, use this:

```
git diff-index -M25%
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What about the version history? If git deems this is a new file, then it is a fresh new version history, isn't it?

Comment: @mark: Let me rephrase that: Git doesn't track version history of individual files *at all.*  It tracks the version history of the entire repository, and uses that information to reconstruct the history for an individual file.

Comment: Still do not get it. Suppose the repository has commits C0, C1, C2. In C3 I deleted file X and added file Y. Then the history of Y would be just C3, right? Buf if I renamed file X to Y, then the history should be C0, C1, C2 and C3. Do I miss anything?

Comment: That is 100% incorrect.  The history of file Y, in Git's database, is *only* in C3.  Nothing you do will ever change this fact, this is the way Git works.

Comment: Let me understand it. If I renamed X to Y and did nothing else (i.e. the content is 100% the same) and checked in, then Y looses all the history it had as X and starts out clean, with just the rename commit? I am going to check it right now, because this is very strange.

Comment: Let me clarify: Y has no history.  The history does not exist.  It does not matter whether you move the file or create a new one or cast a magic spell, because as far as Git is concerned, Y is new because no file named Y existed in the previous commit.  When you use `git log`, `git diff`, or `git status`, etc. Git will try to *guess* what the history of file Y is, but file Y never, ever actually has any recorded history.

Comment: @mark: I think the major problem here is that you still think of a file as having a history.  This may be true from your perspective, but it is absolutely false as far as Git is concerned.  Git does not record file history at all.  Even if you keep a file with the same name, Git *still* doesn't record a history for that file.  Git only records a history for the entire repo as a single unit.  Using the history for the entire repo, Git will try to guess and give you a plausible history for single files, if you ask Git to do that.

Answer (score 8):

As Dietrich Epp [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39149725/1256452), you not only don't have to, you literally *can't*.  I see from comments that you're still struggling with this concept.  It may help to "rewind" a bit and talk about general Version Control System (VCS) theory.

Mercurial, like many (most?) other VCSes, has a strong notion of *file identity*.  This is why you must use `hg mv`, and if you have forgotten to do that, use `hg mv --after`: Mercurial knows that a file of some path was first introduced in some commit *C<sub>n</sub>*, and from that point on, keeps track of the *identity* of that file by recording any rename operations.

Other VCSes do the same thing through other mechanisms, such as mapping the path name into an object identifier (Unix-like "inode number" or ClearCase "OID").  The history of the file is attached, in some way, to this object-ID.  Although Mercurial does not use a numeric OID / inode-number, its trick of following the file through the manifest by recording renames (and copies and removals as well) gives the same result.

Git throws this entire concept away.  Linus declared that you don't need it and therefore he was simply not going to do it.  No file has any identity beyond its existence, or lack thereof, in any commit.  File `foo` in commit *C<sub>0</sub>* is entirely unrelated to file `foo` in commit *C<sub>n</sub>* (where *n* ≠ 0) ... unless, ex post facto, you (or Git) *decide* that it *should* be related.  (See side note below.)

The `git diff` command decides that two files in two different commits are related if they have the same name and/or are sufficiently similar.  Otherwise they are unrelated.  It decides this *on the fly*, at the time you run `git diff`, based on options you pass to `git diff`.  So you get different answers if you run `git diff` twice with different options.  Files `f1` and `f2` may be related (renamed or copied) or related (`f1` deleted, `f2` created).

If you're deeply familiar with VCSes, you'll immediately want to object: *doesn't this interfere with delta compression?*  The answer is yes, it does, but Git doesn't *do* delta compression.

(Wait, what?!?)

Well, let's adjust that a bit.  Git doesn't do delta compression *yet*.

At the level of "loose objects" in a repository, Git does not do delta compression at all.  It just reduces file content to a single hash value and declares that all files that hash to the same value *are* the same file.  The content's hash *is* the content's identity (its name).  So if `f1` in commit *C<sub>0</sub>* is the same, content-wise, as `f2` in commit *C<sub>n</sub>*, then that *content* is stored only once, as an object named by its hash (even if *n = 0*!).

Later, Git makes "pack files" and *does* do delta-compression, but it does so by picking other objects that it thinks will delta-compress well when grouped.  There is a great deal of hair and magic in this object choice, and Git actually steals a glance at file names to do it, but *in principle* at least, it simply waves a magic wand over the entire repository throughout all history and says "ah, if I delta-compress file `blah` from commit `9999999` and internal tree object `1234567` and commit `abcdef2` together in a chain, I get good results, so I'll do that!"

#### Side note: file history

One result of this is that in Git, files don't actually *have* history.  Since there's no real notion of file identity, you have *commit history* but no *file history*.  Git will, however, synthesize a history for you, by diffing each commit against some prior commit(s) and sometimes declaring two files with different path names to be related after all.  Using `git log --follow` does this, for instance.  But it's a hard thing to do in general, and `git log --follow` does it relatively poorly: you can follow *one* path name back through a chain of commits, one commit at a time, and attempt to discover renames.  The code only works when going from newer commits to older ones, so you cannot `git log --follow --reverse where/did/this/get/renamed/to`.  That is, if you know there *was* a file with some path name, and are wondering if it's *still there*, Git is not very good at telling.  (Essentially, you'll want `git log --raw` with a search for an `R` status on the original name.  If you find such a status, you may then need to repeat with the new name, until you have found every rename leading from "the file as I knew it then" to "a file that seems, by content, to be related today".)

Comment: +1 That is a very detailed response. Unfortunately only one can be marked as answer. I wish I knew the rationale behind such a decision. On the surface, it seems weird.

Comment: It's ... unusual, at least.  As far as I know Git is the *only* VCS to take this approach (so far), though I have not investigated DARCS and bzr.